# Calling image in database in ANDROID

Tags: android, database, image

Im a beginner, Please help me. Im so confused.
I want to call my image using database but i dont know how. please help me.
My approach is this. I want to automatically change the image of the imageview when the text view is also changing

```
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qImg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qImg.setText(question);
        ImageView yes = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageQuestions);

        if (qImg.equals("aso"))
            // yes = R.drawable.aso;
            yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aso);

        else if (qImg.equals("Pusa"))
            yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pusa);
        else if (qImg.equals("Daga"))
            yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.daga);
```

question is my questions in the database. it is just a text.And when the question is changin the image is also changing.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking, what your goal is and what the problem is...

Comment: My problem is the image doesnt change when I want to change it. If the text is "Aso" the image need to be "Aso.png" not other image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I *think* you want to change the ImageView contents whenever your TextView's text changes. I'm not sure however, so let me know if I got it wrong.

From the code you've posted, it seems that this will run only once. Instead, you should move this into a method like:

```
public void updateImages() {
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
    TextView qImg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qImg.setText(question);
    ImageView yes = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageQuestions);

    if (qImg.equals("aso"))
        yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aso);
    else if (qImg.equals("Pusa"))
        yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pusa);
    else if (qImg.equals("Daga"))
        yes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.daga);
}
```

Now simply call `updateImages()` right after whenever you call `setText()` in your TextView.

You could also assign a TextWatcher to the TextView:

```
qImg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        YourActivity.this.updateImages();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir Raghav, It is not working for me. The image does not change.

Comment: Try replacing all the qImg.equals with qImg.getText().toString().equals

Comment: whooo cool men it worked.... can I commend you or something . Thanks a lot. That a big help :)